# How to store and retrieve a pdf file in couchdb using java

Tags: java, couchdb

How to store and retrieve a pdf file in couchdb using java.I have tried many links but they all only focus on storing and retrieving images but i am concerned about pdf files.

Here is my code:

```
// Create a BaseDocument
BaseDocument doc = new BaseDocument();
doc.setProperty("site", "www.onabai.com");
doc.setProperty("leitmotif", "Working on a cloud of documents!");
db.createDocument(doc);
System.out.printf("Id: %s rev.: %s\n", doc.getId(), doc.getRevision());
// Add attachment
File file = new File("resources/jcouchdb.svg");
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
String rev = db.createAttachment(doc.getId(), doc.getRevision(),
                                     "logo", "image/svg+xml", is, file.length());
System.out.printf("New rev.: %s\n", rev);
```

I get an error saying method `createAttachment` doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried, or any code you might have already?

Comment: // Create a BaseDocument
BaseDocument doc = new BaseDocument();
doc.setProperty("site", "www.onabai.com");
doc.setProperty("leitmotif", "Working on a cloud of documents!");
db.createDocument(doc);
System.out.printf("Id: %s rev.: %s\n", doc.getId(), doc.getRevision());
 
// Add attachment
File file = new File("resources/jcouchdb.svg");
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
String rev = db.createAttachment(doc.getId(), doc.getRevision(),
                                 "logo", "image/svg+xml",
                                 is, file.length());
System.out.printf("New rev.: %s\n", rev);

Comment: i hav tried this bt it says that there is no method like createAttachment